# MS Excel: How to list all column if the rows contain a given date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx

My data looks like below. I have Groups that I share topics each day. We do this randomly based on need.

[image]

```
|         | Topic 1 | Topic 2 | Topic 3 | Topic 4 | Topic 5 | Topic 6 | Topic 7 | Topic 8 | Topic 9 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| Group 1 |         | 19-apr  | 30-apr  |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| Group 2 | 18-apr  | 25-apr  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| Group 3 |         |         |         |         | 19-apr  | 30-apr  |         |         |         |
| Group 4 | 18-apr  | 25-apr  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| Group 5 |         |         |         |         |         |         | 19-apr  | 30-apr  |         |
| Group 6 |         |         | 25-apr  |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| Group 7 | 18-apr  | 25-apr  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
```

For our metrics & analysis, we need a list of groups per date on a different sheet. We like to know which all groups were engaged a given day. Like below

[image]

Can somebody please help me how I can get this done with only using formulas and without macros?
I believe this can somehow be handled on Index Matching or look-ups.

Comment: Wouldn't you want Group 6 included with 25-Apr? What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely do this with macros. You can do something similar without macros; it may not be precisely what you were looking for because it will leave blank space where groups were not addressed.

**Method 1**
Here is the formula I used and a picture of the sheet it is in:

`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(L$4,$B6:$H6,0),FALSE),INDEX($B$5:$B$13,MATCH($K5,$B$5:$B$13,0),1),"")`
[image]

The idea is that if you have absolute references alongside your list of groups per date, then you can use index and match to fill in that group's name, but only if Match finds that precise date code in that group's row from the previous table. If you place an equivalent formula in the first cell, you can drag it out to the rest of the array.

The formula I used is not the only way to do this, but if you know Index and Match, then it should make sense to you.

**Method 2**

A more convoluted method would be to use image references. With these, it is possible to make the report precisely what you asked for on a separate sheet.

Suppose you took Method 1 and separated each column out into a different table. Nearly the same formula inside the cells below the date heading, except that you enclose the heading reference in `int()` as shown below. Create one table for each of N dates, where N is the number of days you want to monitor at once. Then when you want the summary to show you different dates, you go to each table and change the heading, and filter out blanks.

formula:
`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(INT($L$2),$B4:$H4,1),FALSE),INDEX($B$4:$B$11,MATCH($K3,$B$4:$B$11,1),0),"")`

The below image shows what I mean by one table for each date:
[image]

Then you insert an image. Doesn't matter what image; could be a screenshot of anything. Click on that image, then click into the formula bar. Then highlight the table column you want it to represent. Below is a screenshot of how to to that:

[image]

Now place that picture on its own sheet in the workbook. Place each date table on its own sheet in the workbook. The reason you do this is: if you filter a table, everything else overlapping the filtered rows outside the table will also be hidden. You move tables to separate sheets to prevent them from hiding each other.

Finally, arrange your pictures into the order you like, filter the blanks out of the tables, and your images will be exactly what you were looking for:

[image]

Again, this is a little convoluted because if you want the report to show you new date summaries, you would have to change the headings on every table. Then you would have to go to each table and refresh it's filter. This is where macros usually come in.

Answer (score 0):

Assume range `A1:J8` housed your Source table, and `L1:P8` housed the Date/Group Output

1] In `L2`, copied across :

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$J$8/($B$2:$J$8>K$2),1)),"")
```

2] In `L3`, copied across to P3 and all copied down :

```
=IF(L$2="","",IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$8)/($B$2:$J$8=L$2),ROW(A1))),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to get a list of dates from a table:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,($B$2:$J$8/($B$2:$J$8*(COUNTIF($A$15:A15,$B$2:$J$8)=0)))*$B$2:$J$8,1),"")
```

To get a list of groups by date, use the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(B$15=$B$1:$J$8))*ROW($B$1:$J$8),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]